# SQL Server view - derived date column

Tags: sql-server, view

I have created a view using 2 columns from my `Employee` table like this

```
Create VIEW [dbo].[vwTestEmp] AS 
   select 
       EMpID,
       case when (Address1 IS null) then null
            when (Address1 IS not null) then Address1
       end as "EMpAddress",
       '' as "Date_Verified" 
   FROM Employee;
```

Now `Date_Verified` is not in the `Employee` table, so is a derived column in the view and contains null. After manual verification of certain processes, I want to call

```
update [dbo].[vwTestEmp] 
set Date_verified = GETDATE() 
where EMpid = 60;
```

I am getting an error

> Update or insert of view or function 'vwTestEMp' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

How to handle this error?

THanks
MR

Comment: You know that a non-indexed view doesn't actually store data, right? So what is your update statement actually going to do?

Comment: This date will probably be looked into when updates was done and any discrepancies in the table, we can find out using the date.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what a view is. **It doesn't store data.**

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update the view through the constant value for Date_Verified. Change the query to:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwTestEmp1] AS 
    SELECT EMpID, Address1 AS EMpAddress], [Date_Verified] 
        FROM EMployee;
```

This avoids the unnecessary CASE and replaces the constant value for the date column with the underlying column.

This updates as shown in the [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b11a3/1).

Comment: **`Date_Verified is not in EMployee table`**

Comment: Correct, but if it is to be updatable, it needs to be in some table. If not, the entire question is moot. In which case, I will gladly delete my answer.

Comment: That's why I added my comment above.

Comment: @Pekka, Date_Verified is not in the Employee table any other table

Comment: If so, then the entire point of using an UPDATE has no meaning. It must have a column in some underlying table in order to work. If this is not the correct answer, you will need to expand your question to allow the answers to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error. The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE < view_name > SET<column1>=<value1>,<column2>=<value2>,... WHERE <condition>;
```

Comment: Then i don't know. Maybe this [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqldbauk/2011/08/03/updating-views/) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table.

```
select 
    EMpID,
    Address1 as "EMpAddress",
    '' as "Date_Verified"
INTO [dbo].[tblTestEmp]
FROM Employee;

update [dbo].[tblTestEmp] 
set Date_verified = GETDATE() 
where EMpid = 60;
```

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I did